# Join multiple tables and create a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine

[image: # tables ans resulting table]

I having 3 tables called Advance, Transport and Medicine. I want to join these three tables and come up with a table like last one for emp_id 1. Is it possible to do this in sql level using dql (doctrine) or sql?

Comment: Since you don't need to duplicate your data, I suggest you use a `VIEW` instead.

Comment: They are called RELATIONAL databases for a reason; all tables are relations, and all views are relations, and all queries are relations, but any particular relation need not be a query, a view or a table; merely some implementation of a relation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        Amount As Advance, 
        NULL AS Transport,
        NULL AS Medicine
FROM    Advance
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
UNION   ALL
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        NULL As Advance, 
        Amount AS Transport,
        NULL AS Medicine
FROM    Transport
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
UNION   ALL
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        NULL As Advance, 
        NULL AS Transport,
        Amount AS Medicine
FROM    Medicine
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
```

- [CREATE TABLE...SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

You can also create a `VIEW` on this,

```
CREATE VIEW EmployeeView
AS
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        Amount As Advance, 
        NULL AS Transport,
        NULL AS Medicine
FROM    Advance
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
UNION   ALL
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        NULL As Advance, 
        Amount AS Transport,
        NULL AS Medicine
FROM    Transport
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
UNION   ALL
SELECT  Date, 
        Emp_ID,
        NULL As Advance, 
        NULL AS Transport,
        Amount AS Medicine
FROM    Medicine
WHERE   Emp_ID = 1           -- remove this WHERE clause to include all emp_ID
```

- [CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)